# Instruments in a Desert Society

Tags: music

I am creating a desert country with humanoid people inhabiting it. I would like to see what kinds of instruments they would have. Their technology level is around a mid-1800’s level.

Many musical instruments are made with wood, but in this desert society, there is very little wood, and that small amount comes from trade with other countries.

I would like to understand what the “traditional instruments” of this desert country would be, and since there is little wood available, the instruments probably won’t be made of wood.

The instrument can be anything with definite or indefinite pitch, but here, the voice is not counted as an instrument.

Comment: People have been trading long distances since before the invention of agriculture. With mid 1800s level technology they should be capable of accessing resources from anywhere on earth to construct their instruments. As such your country can have whatever instruments you want them to have.

Comment: If we look at the desert nomads of the mid 1800's, Their technology level was very traditional with a few firearms gotten from trading / raiding.

Comment: What has your research so far brought to light? How do your humanoid-made instruments deviate from the kind of instruments desert peoples in the mid-1800s played?

Comment: They are different from what desert peoples played because there is little wood available, even less than what contemporary societies would have had.

Comment: By 1830 ice cut from ponds in New England was shipped as far away as Australia. If you assume a  mid-1800’s level of technology then you have international trade and access to basically any natural material there is a demand for. Combine this with the fact that instruments are not a bulk good but a luxury item and local access to wood becomes a non factor. By weight there's not a lot of material in most instruments relative to their cost. A single wagon could carry enough raw material to outfit a whole band, even before you consider the option of shipping in finished instruments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of your other options can include stringed instruments, using gut or sinew strings. Such instruments may use bone bows, strung with animal hair and natural rosin.

Depending how adept your society is at metalworking, bone horns could also give way to metal ones, and metal could also be used with skin heads and gut or leather tensioners to create tuned drums like timpani, or ones with resonators, like snare drums.

Answer (score 4):

What do they have?

**Animal parts**

- Horns (wind instruments, percussion)
- Skins (tambourines, percussion)
- Bones (striking tools, xylophonic, thanks @L.Dutch for wind instruments)
- Snake rattles

**Rocks**

- Percussion (hollowing out rocks of various sizes might actually be pretty cool)

And the desert isn't as devoid of wood as you might think. Think "woody" rather than "wood," which means credible reed instruments.

**Human**

- Voice

Consider the Bedouin [Rebab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedouin_music).

Comment: You could add brass / metal to the list, as well as wood and cane / bamboo. Considering the native instruments of North African countries, all of these materials are used!

Comment: @elemtilas You're completely right. I was short on time when I wrote this. My goal was to point out that the instruments will be a function of resource availability. The OP needs to determine what resources will be available and then think through how those resources can be used to produce sound.

Comment: Speaking of "woody rather than wood", I bet you could hollow out saguaro rib and make a flute out of it.

Answer (score 2):

On earth population living in desert area still uses wood for making drums or wind instruments. Yours can do the same.

Also, long bones can be used for making simple flutes, and flat bones as percussion surface.

Answer (score 1):

One option is singing stones, stones with such high metal content they ring like bells. See [Gizmodo article](https://gizmodo.com/listen-to-the-strange-phenomenon-of-singing-stones-1640340333)

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest you take a look at Amazigh tribes music? There are a lot of tribes that have lived in the desert for centuries (e.g. Tuareg and Kabyle)

And the music is quite beautiful - example of this (although modernized) is [Tinariwen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vACZA9dGvV4)

Answer (score 0):

There's also clay. For example [ocarina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocarina) is made from it.